# Elasticsearch 2.3.1 Java API for filter and aggregation with date range

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I am working on ElasticSearch 2.3.1. I have a requirement to fetch data for last 90 days. In this I need data as well as minute wise aggregation. Problem which I am facing is that I am able to get data for last 90 days **but not able to apply date range on the aggregation.**

So I have two problems

Problem 1 – This should work on a result set of a **match query field is different.**

**Problem 2 – Java API for the above query**

Query which I am using is as follows:

```
GET _search
{
    "aggs": {
    "t1": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "from" : "now-1d/d",
        "to" : null,
        "format" : "epoch_millis",
        "include_lower" : true,
        "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "t2": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "1m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In short I need Java API of following type

```
Java API for full:
match query {
  aggregation {
     filter aggregation,
     date histogram
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Problem 1 the following query works:

```
GET _search {
 "query": {
  "match": {
   "body": "Text_To_Search"
  }
 },
 "aggs": {
  "outer_agg": {
   "filter": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [{
      "range": {
       "timestamp": {
        "from": "now-90d/d",
        "to": null,
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "include_lower": true,
        "include_upper": true
       }
      }
     }]
    }
   },
   "aggs": {
    "inner_agg": {
     "date_histogram": {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "interval": "1m"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The Java API for the same is:

```
DateHistogramBuilder dhb = AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("t2").field("timestamp").interval(DateHistogramInterval.MINUTE);

BoolQueryBuilder bqb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").gte("now-90d").to("now").format("epoch_millis"));

FilterAggregationBuilder fab = AggregationBuilders.filter("t1").filter(bqb).subAggregation(dhb);

SearchResponse sr = TEFESConnector.getInstance().getClient().prepareSearch("index_name").setTypes("type_name").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field_to_search", "text_to_search")).addAggregation(fab).execute().actionGet();
```